# Can't run NiFi on OSX

Tags: homebrew, apache-nifi

I installed NiFi on my OSX machine using

```
brew install nifi
```

This worked fine, but when I run the command

```
nifi run
```

I checked the nifi-app log and this is what pops out:

```
2017-10-27 00:24:26,211 WARN [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command 
Launched Apache NiFi but could not determined the Process ID
```

I tried `nifi start`as well but get the following as status:

```
2017-10-27 00:26:48,081 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.bootstrap.Command 
Apache NiFi is currently running, listening to Bootstrap on port 
50289, PID=unknown
```

Not sure if I have to edit something, but I'm concerned by PID is unknown.

EDIT:
When running

```
2017-10-27 11:14:13,809 ERROR [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Failure to 
launch NiFi due to java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider 
org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ParseCEF could not be instantiated
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: 
org.apache.nifi.processor.Processor: Provider 
org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ParseCEF could not be instantiated
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:799)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(ServiceLoader.java:721)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(ServiceLoader.java:1389)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.loadExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:142)
    at org.apache.nifi.nar.ExtensionManager.discoverExtensions(ExtensionManager.java:117)
    at org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer.start(JettyServer.java:702)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.<init>(NiFi.java:160)
    at org.apache.nifi.NiFi.main(NiFi.java:268)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.parseValidationXml(ConfigurationImpl.java:357)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.createBootstrapConfiguration(ConfigurationImpl.java:349)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.prepare(ConfigurationImpl.java:340)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.__privileged_doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:329)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ParseCEF.<init>(ParseCEF.java:179)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(ServiceLoader.java:777)
    ... 7 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:466)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Those are only INFO and WARN only.Did you check that port was listening or not?

Comment: @Maehndra prabhu - I tried but it actually shuts down.. `nifi run` displays the message and then immediately shuts down

Comment: Is there anything of interest in the logs, particularly nifi-app.log?  You can access it via `less $(brew --prefix nifi)/libexec/logs/nifi-app.log`.  If there is nothing of interest there, also look at nifi-bootstrap.log.  Update the question with any interesting lines from either.

Answer (score 3):

I was using JDK 9. Turns out as of today, this doesn't work. I downgraded to JDK 8 and voila! Thanks y'all

Answer (score 1):

No need to download to JDK 8, but you do need it installed.

## Picking which JDK to Run

I have an app (nifi) which does not work on JDK 9, so I want to switch the JDK Version.

## List Possible Versions

This is the command

```
 /usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

And the correctponing output

```
Matching Java Virtual Machines (2):
    9.0.1, x86_64:  "Java SE 9.0.1" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
    1.8.0_151, x86_64:  "Java SE 8" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home

/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

## Set your Java-Home

For picking just a major Version you can do this

```
export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
```

### Run App (nifi)

I now just need to select this Java, export it. And run the startup script...

`` export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8`
tim@T-Mac-mini bin $ java -version
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
tim@TMac-mini bin $ ./nifi.sh run ``

It now works.